# Python adding to a nested list

Tags: python, nested-lists

```
n = int(len(network))
num=[]

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):

        num[i].append(int (between_lists(network[i],network[j])))
return num
```

this error message I get

```
 num[i].append(int (between_lists(network[i],network[j])))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Hint: where the code says `num[i].append`, notice how it does **not** say `num[i][j] =`? Do you understand why it would be wrong to try to add elements to `num[i]` that way? Now, think carefully about the `num[i]` part. Doesn't the same problem apply there? After all, what is `num` before the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Any of your three indexing operations *could* be the cause, but `num` is *definitely* an empty `list`, so you can't index it at all. Did you perhaps mean to append to `num` itself, not to a sublist within `num` (which has no inner `list`s at all)?

```
num.append(int (between_lists(network[i],network[j])))
 # ^ removed [i]
```

Update: Based on your comments, you want a new sublist for each run of the outer loop, so what you really wanted is:

```
for i in range(n):
    num.append([])  # Put in new sublist
    for j in range(n):
        num[i].append(int(between_lists(network[i],network[j])))
return num
```

Comment: it works, but I am try to get results like this [[3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3], [0, 5, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0], [1, 3, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 4, 3, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1], [2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 5, 2], [3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 4]]

Comment: but this is what I get [5, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 3, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 5, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 4]